# find the estimate of the tangent line approximation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

Suppose that $f(x)$ is a function with $f(130)=46$ and $f′(130)=1$. Estimate $f(125.5)$.

I looked at the problem multiple times, but I am still stumped!

Comment: Did you mean find the estimate *with* the tangent line approximation?

Comment: yes with the tangent line approximation

Answer (score 0):

Use $f(x)\approx f(130)+(x-130)f'(130)$.

(The tangent line will have slope $f'(130)$ and contain the point $(130,f(130)$.)